# Android - How to add a bottom (focused) border to spinner?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

How can I add a bottom border to my spinner, like the Google Add new contact (see image)?
Then, when I click on the spinner, in Google Add new contact, the border becomes blue.

My spinner has this code:

```
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/insert_type"
        android:prompt="@string/insert_type_title"/>
```

[image: Add contact screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Late to the party, but you can use `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined`

Comment: Late, but the only. Thank you so much!